How can I update the records in SQL Server base on the given output at Azure DataBricks table?
Let's say that I have a table in Azure and SQL Server with a day 1 value of this. superceded_to_sku is the field that will contain the updated version of SKU_ERP and should be the new value in SQL Server table.
Azure Table



SKU_ERP
superceded_to_sku




ABC123




SQL Server Table



SKU_ERP




ABC123



In day 2 the Azure table is now updated with the following records
Azure Table



SKU_ERP
superceded_to_sku




ABC123
DEF456


WXY159




Ideally the output for SQL Server should be:
SQL Server Table



SKU_ERP




DEF456


WXY159



For reference here is the code that I'm using:
%python
#OBTAINING hierarchy_id
str_query = f"""
SELECT 
    A.hierarchy_id
FROM [SOP].[RMBHierarchy] A
JOIN [SOP].[Regions] B ON A.region_id = B.region_id
JOIN [SOP].[Markets] C ON A.market_id = C.market_id
JOIN [SOP].[Brands] D ON A.brand_id = D.brand_id
WHERE B.region_name= '{region}' AND
C.market_name = '{market}' AND
D.brand_name= '{brand}';"""

hierarchy_id = select_query(str_query)['hierarchy_id'][0]
print(f'hierarchy_id: {hierarchy_id}, region: {region}, market: {market}, brand: {brand}')


#Azure table
#string query for updating
string_query = f"""
  SELECT 
    TRIM(SKU_ERP) AS sku_erp,
    TRIM(SKU_Code) AS sku_code,
    TRIM(coalesce(Superceded_To_SKU,'')) AS superceded_to_sku
  FROM {schema_source_name}.{table_source_name}
  WHERE Region = '{region}'
  AND Market = '{market}'
  AND Brand = '{brand}'"""

df_global_parts = spark.sql(string_query)
df_global_parts = df_global_parts.replace('null', None)
df_global_parts = df_global_parts.withColumn("hierarchy_id", lit(hierarchy_id))
df_global_parts_update = df_global_parts.filter(col("superceded_to_sku")!='')

#string query for ingesting new records
string_query = f"""
  SELECT 
    TRIM(SKU_ERP) AS sku_erp,
    TRIM(SKU_Code) AS sku_code,
  FROM {schema_source_name}.{table_source_name}
  WHERE Region = '{region}'
  AND Market = '{market}'
  AND Brand = '{brand}'
  AND TRIM(COALESCE(Superceded_To_SKU,'')) = '' """

df_latest_data_sku = spark.sql(string_query)
df_latest_data_sku = df_latest_data_sku.replace('null', None)
df_latest_data_sku = df_latest_data_sku.withColumn("hierarchy_id", lit(hierarchy_id))


#ingestion of new records
#Inserting data from Azure table Table to SQL table 
#with latest SKU_ERP
str_query = f"""SELECT TOP (1) * FROM [SOP].[table] WHERE hierarchy_id = '{hierarchy_id}'"""
df_mas_data = select_query(str_query)

if(df_mas_data.empty):
  batch_limit = 10000
  lower_limit = 1
  upper_limit = batch_limit
  while True:
    df_batch_data = df_latest_data_sku.filter((col("index_column") >= lower_limit) & (col("index_column") <= upper_limit))
    if df_batch_data.limit(1).count() == 0:
      break

    json_data = df_batch_data.toJSON().collect()
    json_data = "[" + ",".join(json_data) + "]"
    print(f"Batch: {lower_limit} - {upper_limit}")
    exec_stored_procedure("[SOP].[usp_OnBoarding_table](?)", json_data)
    lower_limit = upper_limit + 1
    upper_limit = upper_limit + batch_limit  


#updating the records
#updating data from Azure table Table to SQL table 
#with superceded_to_sku

str_query = f''' 
SELECT *
FROM [SOP].[MasterData]
WHERE hierarchy_id = '{hierarchy_id}'
ORDER BY master_id
OFFSET ({batch_number})*{chunk_size}
ROWS FETCH NEXT {chunk_size} ROWS ONLY;'''
df_master_data = spark.createDataFrame(select_query(str_query))
# from pyspark.sql.functions import col, regexp_replace, lit, count

df_global_parts_update1 = (
    df_global_parts_update
    .withColumn('sku_erp', col('superceded_to_sku'))
    .withColumn('sku_code', regexp_replace(col('superceded_to_sku'), ' ', ''))
    .withColumn('superceded_to_sku', lit(''))
    # .distinct()
)

df_duplicates_count = (
    df_global_parts_update
    .groupBy('superceded_to_sku')
    .agg(count('*').alias('duplicate_count'))
    # .filter(col('duplicate_count') > 1)  # Only keep rows that have duplicates
)
display(df_duplicates_count)

As I state before the ideal output should be that the SKU_ERP column at SQL Server table must be updated and that updated value should be coming from superceded_to_sku. I've only managed to ingest the Dataframe from df_latest_data_sku, I'm still figuring out on how to do it for df_global_parts_update.
